# Why am i getting request timed out on my console when trying to ping a computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I want to make sure that whether i can send some data from my system to my roommate's system.For that,i tried to ping his computer,but i am getting "request timed out error" and 100% loss of data.My system is on the Ethernet LAN and his system is on the Wi-Fi LAN Of the college.I just want to know what may be the reasons behind this ?
Can someone help me out of this,so that i will be able to send data to his computer?

Here is the o/p on console.

```
Pinging 10.64.17.50 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.64.17.50:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: Windows Firewall blocking ICMP? What happens if both of you are on the same network either both on Ethernet or both on Wireless?

Comment: @ Matt King,I tried it,now also same error is on the console.(100% loss)

Comment: You can try a traceroute  (aka tracert in windows command line)

Comment: @infixed,tracert is giving the same error "request timed out".

Comment: Then something is dropping packet, `tracert` basically sends out a packet with a varying "time to live count", 1, then 2, then 3, etc.   When a packet's TTL decrements each hop, and when it reaches zero it's supposed to get dropped and an ICMP packet sent back saying was dropped.  If both `ping` and `tracert` are not working, that's like all ICMP packets are getting dropped.    Maybe by your PC's firewall, because usually one's subnet's gateway is reachable by ICMP

Answer (score 1):

It could be several things

- You could have the wrong address, because being behind a WiFi router
  he has a NAT address you are not in the same subnet with
- His computer might be sleeping
- His computer firewall may be set to not respond to pings

I would suspect the NAT thing first

[EDIT]

If you want to make sure you are on the same subnet, and are in the same room, the easiest thing to do may be to obtain an Ethernet switch (sometimes called a hub, but there is a technical difference),  plug it in where your computer is now, then plug both your PC and you roommate's PC to the hub via wire.

Then you are definitely all on the same subnet, and if you have issues, then you can start looking at whether you have firewall problems in your PCs or something.

You may wish to review if your campus has some sort of restrictions for adding a new Ethernet switch to the network like that, because some places actually track who is plugged into what.  But many don't.

Comment: ,what is the remedy for this,because it's compulsory for me to set the connection with his computer,because then only i will be able to test my code of chat server whether working or not working.

Comment: You are going to have to figure out what the network topology really is.  If you are testing some sort of client/server thing, then NAT will be a problem.   Some sort of VPN might be an answer.   If you are really in the same room, you can get a Ethernet hub, and you both plug into it via a wire.   Or perhaps a crossover Ethernet cable is even enough  (many Ethernet NICs these day will automagically do the crossover for you, and you could use any wire)   You'll have to set your own IP addresses if you decide to isolate yourself from the infrastructure networks though

Comment: What i noticed is that my computer is not able to ping even google server"www.google.com". Same "request timed out errror is coming".

Comment: Your router may not be configured to pass ICMP (ping etc).  If you do a traceroute (tracert) towards google, you can probably see some of what your network looks like.  You can try pinging your gateway just to gain some confidence that your machine can do pings and its not firewalled off on your end.  If you are on windows, you could do a command line `ipconfig /all` and see what it reports for your Ethernet adapter as an IP address and gateway

Answer (score 0):

Ping requires the cooperation of your computer, the end computer, and all the computers (routers, etc.) in between.

[Ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) tells you if the entire route permits ICMP packets. Determining connectivity from this is more of a side-effect these days.

[Traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) (`tracert` or `traceroute`) also does pings (sends [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets) but sets a "number of hops" ([TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live), time to live) on each packet. In this way, you can roughly determine what route your connection goes through to get where it's going. Often there will be machines along the way that pass the ICMP packets, but won't respond the them. These show as unresponsive machines along the route. Sometimes you'll get a situation where partway through the route you appear to get a long list of machines that are unresponsive. This is usually due to a machine along the way discarding the ICMP packets.

For your situation, the scenarios are:

- Your roommate's computer blocks ICMP packets (usually a firewall setting)
- Your wireless router segregates the wired and wireless networks (a common security setting in wireless routers)
- The campus network blocks ICMP packets (unlikely but possible)

Answer (score -2):

You need to check the routes
ex. route print
then check if there are any routes which you have added manually
If yes, Delete it